# Sending mail from command line if body not empty

Tags: email, bash, cron, command-line-interface, gnu

I'd like to write a simple script that alerts me if a log changes. For this I'm using grep to find the lines I'm interested in. Right now it works like this:

```
grep line /var/log/file | mail -s Log email@domain.tld
```

Problem is that this sends a mail even if no matching lines are found. The mail utility from GNU Mailutils seems to have no switch telling it to drop mails that have an empty body.

Is there a quick and easy way to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
output=$(grep line /var/log/file); [[ -n "$output" ]] && mail -s Log email@domain.tld
```

Or you can make this into a cron job and then if it produces any output it will email the users. You can edit the /etc/aliases file (and then run newaliases command) to send mail to address not on the box.

Ex of cron entry (You won't be able to set the subject line thogh

```
1 0 * * *  grep line /var/log/file
```

Or you can get the ifne utility - This is probably what you want

grep line /var/log/file | ifne mail -s Log email@domain.tld

The ifne command it availabe from the epel repo for centos and RHEL. I can't find a link to the man page online but there it is

> ifne(1)
>   ifne(1)
>
> NAME
>          ifne - Run command if the standard input is not empty
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          ifne [-n] command
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          ifne  runs  the  following command if and only if the standard input is
>          not empty.
>
> OPTIONS
>          -n     Reverse operation. Run the command if the standard input is emp-
>                 ty.
>
> ```
>           Note  that  if  the  standard  input  is not empty, it is passed
>           through ifne in this case.
> ```
>
> EXAMPLE
>          find . -name core | ifne mail -s "Core files found" root
>
> AUTHOR
>          Copyright 2008 by Javier Merino
>
> ```
>    Licensed under the GNU GPL
>
>                               2008-05-01                           ifne(1)
> ```

Comment: Note that grep will exit non-0 if it generates no output, so you could do: output=$(grep line /var/log/file) && echo "$output" | mail -s Log user@example.com

Comment: Also, your suggested command doesn't send "$output" to the mail command.  :-)

Comment: I would suggest editing the answer to include the proposed solution by @Sean Reifschneider

Comment: FYI `ifne` is found in the `moreutils` package in ubuntu. Unfortunately that package also brings in `parallel` which conflicts with the `parallel` command from the `parallel` package.

Answer (score 15):

"man mail" tells me that the argument -E stopps sending mails if body is empty. works fine for me.

> -E
>
> If an outgoing message does not contain any text in its first or
>                 only message part, do not  send  it  but  discard  it  silently,
>                 effectively   setting  the  skipemptybody  variable  at  program
>                 startup.  This is  useful  for  sending  messages  from  scripts
>                 started by cron(8).

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, GNU Mailtools 2.1 is installed, and the "-E" option for "mail" there is a shorthand for --exec. It does not contain an "empty body" option.

Comment: @MarkStosberg: Ubuntu has multiple alternative packages providing a `mail` or `mailx` command. The `bsd-mailx` and `heirloom-mailx` packages both provide a `mailx` with the `-E` option described here.

Comment: Worked for me on CentOS 6.5: `grep "find me" /var/log/something | mail -s "That text you were looking for is now in the logs" -E mail@example.com`

Answer (score 3):

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100720/27458

Just use **ifne**:

```
grep line /var/log/file | ifne mail -s Log email@domain.tld
```